# Is the data statistically significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

A tiger killed 60 villagers in the year 2018. The villagers came up with a technique to wear a mask on the back of their heads to prevent the tiger from attacking from the back. They did this for an entire year and the deaths due to tiger for 2019 was calculated to be 52. The villagers are convinced their technique worked.

Is there any way to tell if the reduction in deaths is statistically significant? Can we do a hypothesis test or do we need more data?

Comment: You need additional information about the rate of exposure to the risk.  For instance, awareness of the risk may have caused villagers to work less in the fields in 2019; or conversely, belief in the mitigation may have caused them to work much more in 2019. Thus, the mortality figures alone are meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

**Normal approximation to binomial test.** In order to do a test of binomial proportions one would need
an estimate of the size of the village population, which
presumably has not changed from 2018 to 2019. Just as an experiment let's suppose it is $n = 5000.$ Then we can test the null hypothesis $H_0: p_{18}=p_{19}$ that the proportion of deaths due to the
tiger has not changed by wearing masks, against the alternative
$H_a: p_{18} > p_{19}.$

Then the procedure `prop.test` in R, which uses a normal approximation, goes as shown below. The null hypothesis is
not rejected (large P-value), so there is no statistically
significant evidence that masks offer protection against
deadly tiger attacks. [The test statistic `X-squared` is
the square of a normal z-statistic.]

```
prop.test(c(60, 52), c(5000,5000), alt="less")

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(60, 52) out of c(5000, 5000)
X-squared = 0.44246, df = 1, p-value = 0.747
alternative hypothesis: less
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.000000000  0.005261848
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
0.0120 0.0104
```

Technically speaking, the P-value depends on the population
size assumed for the village, but for reasonable assumptions
the interpretation of the test is the same.

**Normal approximation to Poisson test.** Suppose the village
rates of tiger deaths in the two years are $\lambda_{18}$ and
$\lambda_{19},$ respectively. Then we can test
$H_0: \lambda_{18}-\lambda_{19}=\delta=0$ against the alternative
$H_0: \lambda_{18}-\lambda_{19}=\delta>0.$ In this formulation,
we estimate $\delta$ by $\hat\delta = X - Y = 60-52 = 8.$
Then, under $H_0,$ we have $E(\hat \delta) = 0,$
$Var(\hat\delta) = 120,$ and $SD(\hat\delta) = \sqrt{120} = 10.95.$

The z-statistic
$Z = (\hat\delta-\delta)/SD(\hat\delta) = 8/10.95 = 0.79 < 2.573,$ where $2.576$ cuts probability 5% from the upper tail of a standard normal distribution. Thus $H_0$ is not rejected.
Also, the P-value is $P(Z > 0.79|H_0) = 0.2148 > 0.05.$

```
1-pnorm(0.79)
[1] 0.2147639
```

**Parametric bootstrap one-sided confidence interval for $\delta.$**
For $\lambda$ as small as $60.$ one may question whether the
normal approximation gives reasonable P-values. A parametric
bootstrap procedure estimates the distribution of $\hat\delta$
by taking repeated samples of $\hat\delta$ from distributions
suggested by the data. We use $B = 10,000$ such re-sampled estimates
$\hat \delta,$ called `Del` in the R code below.

```
del.obs = 8
set.seed(1226)
x = rpois(10^4, 60);  y = rpois(10^5, 52)
Del = x - y
summary(Del)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -49.00    1.00    8.00    8.01   15.00   57.00 
quantile(Del, .95)
95% 
 25
```

The 95% upper bound for $\delta$ is $25.$ Our estimate is far
below this bound, and so we can believe that $\hat \delta = 8$
is consistent with no benefit from wearing masks to keep tigers
from killing villagers.

The histogram of simulated values `Del` of $\hat \delta$ illustrates that the sampling distribution of $\hat\delta$ is not far from
normal. The 95% upper bound is shown as a vertical red line.

```
hist(Del, br=-50.5:60.5, prob=T)
 abline(v=25, col="red")
 curve(dnorm(x,mean(Del),sd(Del)), add=T, col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I've got a doubt. You've assumed the population of the village to be 1000 but in your r code snippet, what is that 5000?

Comment: Sorry 1000 was typo, changed it to 5000 as in code. (1000 is pretty small for village with 60 deaths from tigers.)

Answer (score 0):

One simple option, if you know the total population in both years, is to do a test for [equality of proportions](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/9/9.4), where you compare the proportion of villagers who died due to tigers in 2018 to the proportion of villagers who died due to tigers in 2019.